# Write characteristic to BLE device using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am not having any luck writing a string to my BLE device. Every time I call `gatt.writeCharacteristic(mChar)` it return false and nothing happens.

The string value I need to write looks like this:

> “120,20,0,Foo, 0.0”

I wrote an iOS app and have my string formatted just like this. So I know it isn't the structure of the string. I have tried a simple call of `mChar.value = mString.toByteArray()` then `gatt.writeCharacteristic(mChar)`. This fails. Is there something I am missing here? Should I even be trying to convert it to a byte array?

A second idea is something like this `mChar.setValue(URLEncoder.encode(mString, "utf-8"))`. I actually don't know how this is different. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you included the BLUETOOTH permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes, this is actually the second BLE device for this app.

Comment: You need to show more code. It can return false for many reasons, but usually because you already have another pending GATT operation.